# Choosing an arbitrary dimension to filter over?

Tags: multidimensional-array, julia

In Julia, is there a good way to "choose to loop over an arbitrary dimension" `d`? For example, I want to apply a diffusion filter to a 2D `x` I want to do

```
for j = 1:size(x,2)
  for i = 2:size(x,1)-1
    x2[i,j] = x[i-1,j] - 2x[i,j] + x[i+1,j]
  end
end
```

But I want to write a function `diffFilter(x2,x,d)` where `x` can be an arbitrary dimension array and `d` is any dimension less than `ndims(x)`, and it applies this `x[i-1] + 2x[i] - x[i+1]` filter along the dimension `d` (into `x2` without allocating). Any idea how to do the indexing such that I can use that `d` to have that special part of the loop be the `d`th index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard library function `mapslices` does this. You can write a function that applies the filter to a vector, and `mapslices` will take care of applying it to a particular dimension.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to look at the pair of blog posts that Tim Holy has written on the subject:

- http://julialang.org/blog/2016/02/iteration
- http://julialang.org/blog/2016/03/arrays-iteration

That should give you a start on the subject.